# Image in Simple HTML

Tags: html

which is ideal place to place image in NEtbeans for HTML

```
enter code here

  <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Android Stuff</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="WEB-INF/SC20111215-165000 (1).png" width="240" height="400" alt="SC20111215-   165000 (1)"/>

  </body>
<  /html>
```

Comment: check you image name and path.

Comment: Self-close your `<meta>` tag (add a `/` before the `>`)

Comment: I recommend you to not use image names with whitespaces "SC20111215-165000_(1).png"

Comment: `WEB-INF` should not be considered for the path, coz it is root folder for your website.

Comment: I ahve checked image path...it seems its proper in web_inf folder
meta tag i dont think there is need to close it..
i have tried removing white space from name.

Comment: Murtaza....if web-inf is not place then where should i keep image.

Comment: Because there are two kinds of HTML tags: self-closing, and non self-closing. If you don't self-close it, the parser will expect a second `</meta>` tag. Most browsers will handle the problem, but its better to be safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the image in the folder where the html file is present.

And change the html code to :

```
<img src="SC20111215-165000 (1).png" width="240" height="400"/>
```

Comment: Thank u for response..but image is in the same folder

Comment: What is the website, so we can check?

Comment: @MrLister ...sir its not live project i am just trying to make some website

Comment: @Sebs_Jedi then tell us the exact path on your computer where the html file is located, and the exact path of the image.

Answer (score 3):

```
<img alt=""  src="img/header960.png" align="center" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind of issues occurs when

1. Path given is wrong
2. Name of image is wrong
3. Extension of image file is wrong

Check the above possibilities. If these 3 are correctly given,
then try with another image with simple name in same folder where the html file is present.

Comment: Can u suggest me how to give path to image in HTML .I would prefer to make new package nad add that as resource. I ahve tried.~/Web and ../web none of them working

Comment: @SameeraThilakasiri by 'Extension' i mean the file format.ie, jpeg,jpg,png etc.

Comment: @Hariviswadeep He has used .png, I dont think issue with the image extension, please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of the image and also its path if possible... Because in most cases these things makes trouble...

```
<img src="newimagenamewithoutspace.png" width="240" height="400" alt="newimagenamewithoutspace"/>
```

And if the image has been posted by a use from front end then try to change the image name in your backend code..

This should help you..

Vote up or accept if it works

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="test.png" width="240" height="400" alt="test">
```

see more Attribute in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp